# CSV Split Method Printing first field twice in 1 column

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, csv

I have a program that is almost done. The issue is that when I print out the "new" CSV file every thing is correct except the very first column in excel. It is printing the information twice but only in the first column. I have looked throughout my code and am unable to see where I would be printing it out twice or calling the token twice.

The purpose of the program is to simply re-organize the columns and format them into a desired manner. The token I am accessing is at position `inputBuffer[23]` and I have it set to be equal to `outputBuffer[0]` and I only do this 1 time but when I run the program and check the file, the first column of the first record should hold the value `841` but instead it is coming up `841841` and I have no clue how. All of the other columns are perfectly fine.

Can anyone spot what's wrong?

### My Method

---

```
/*
 * This method uses the fields (array elements) in the output
 * buffer to assemble a CSV record (string variable). The
 * CSV record is then written to the output file.
 */
public static void BuildRecordAndWriteOutput()
{
    string record = outputBuffer[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
    {
        if (outputBuffer[i].Contains(","))
            {
                string x = "\"" + outputBuffer[i] + "\"";
                record += x;
            }
            else
            {
                record += outputBuffer[i];
            }
            if (i < outputBuffer.Length - 1)
            {
                record += ",";
            }
    }

    /*for (int i = 1; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
    {
        record = record + "," + outputBuffer[i];
    }*/

    output.WriteLine(record);

}
```

### When I call the method

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    input.SetDelimiters(",");

    /*
     * This loop reads input data and calls methods to
     * build an output record and write data to a CSV file.
     */ 
    while (!input.EndOfData)
    {
        inputBuffer = input.ReadFields(); // Read a CSV record in to the inputBuffer.
        SetOutputBufferDefaultValues(); // Put default values in the output buffer.
        MapInputFieldsToOutputFields(); // Move fields from the input buffer to the output buffer.
        BuildRecordAndWriteOutput(); // Build record from output buffer and write it.
    }

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    input.Close();
    output.Close();
    Console.Read();
}
```

### Here is a screenshot in case my explanation was not clear

---

[image]

There is more data to the code and I have not posted it all , as of now, but I can if it will help.

Thanks!

Comment: you initialize record to `outputBuffer[0];` then in the loop you append `outputBuffer[i]` so when i==0....

Comment: While getting an answer here is great, you should invest time in learning how to debug.  Stepping through the application and checking the value of `record` would have shown the issue as soon as you went into your `for` loop.

Comment: @EdT I agree 100% and am doing so. I have already had to practice debugging quite a bit for this program. I honestly just became frustrated with this since it's the only thing left wrong. I am learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `BuildRecordAndWriteOutput`, you assign record:

```
string record = outputBuffer[0];
```

then start your loop at 0, *appending* `outputbuffer[0]` to record:

```
for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
{
    record += ....
}
```

That's what's causing your first column to have the data duplicated.

You can fix this by simply initializing your record to an empty string before the loop:

```
string record = "";
```

Comment: AYE I see now! So by `appending` I was adding what I was picking up in the loop to `outputBuffer[0]` because I was saying that the record already held the value. Is this correct thinking? Thank you so much for teaching and explaining!